# Is it possible to connect attributes from one class to be used in another in python?

Tags: python, class, subclass

I'm beginner in python and I've been coding for month now. I decided to make a simple game project (in pygame) where player(circle) would be moving in towards mouse cursor using vectors.

```
import pygame
import random
import pyautogui 
#Add Mouse class and use pyautogui.position() to return mouse position later on

pygame.init()

screen_width, screen_height = 500, 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, circle_color, circle_radius, circle_outline_width):
        self.circle_color = circle_color
        self.coordinates = (x, y)
        self.circle_radius = circle_radius
        self.circle_outline_widht = circle_outline_width

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.circle_color, self.coordinates, self.circle_radius)
```

My player class with basic attributes needed to make a player ^^^^

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_circle_position(self):
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            circle_position = f"Circle at X: {self.x}, Y:{self.y}"
            return circle_position
```

My Point class which is supposed to read circle position at any given moment. Problem is (I know this code is wrong) I want to use `self.x` and `self.y` from Player class which are coordinates of player from spawn moment and I don't want to repeat whole code again. I don't know if that's possible? And how?

Rest of the code with `def main()`

```
def constantly_display(window, player):
    window.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    player.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    run = True
    p = Player(random.randint(35, screen_width - 40), random.randint(35, screen_height - 40),
               pygame.Color((random.randint(0, 200)),
                            (random.randint(0, 200)),
                            (random.randint(0, 200))), 40, 5)
    c = Point(p, p)
    p.getposition = c
    while run:
        p.getposition.get_circle_position()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
        constantly_display(screen, p)
main()
```

Another problem is how to connect all that into `def main()`? (Code/Syntax improvements gladly appreciated)
Thank you!

Comment: It's not very clear to me why you've got two classes here. Can you clarify what exactly determines which bit of code goes in one versus the other? Perhaps you want `self.coordinates = Point(x, y)` in `Player.__init__`, but it would make a lot more sense to put the mouse-seeking code in `Player` rather than `Point` (which I'd expect to be more about vector math stuff).

Comment: @Blckknght I wanted to make game organized by classes, just for a simple practice and possiblity of adding more and more players later on, to see how it will make difference, ultimate end point would be to make it multiplayer, that's why i thought i needed classes so each player has it's own attributes, circle tracker, and mouse tracker. I want to somehow inherit self.x and self.y which are circle cords in Player class and use it in Point class, and main function to have circle/player tracker. Same would go for Mouse class then I'd add Point cords to Mouse cords for player movements.

Comment: Classes are good, but you need to learn how to combine them properly. You've not really communicated why your `Point` class should exist separate from the `Player` class, or what "circle tracking" means in this context. There are *lots* of ways you could access the `x` and `y` coordinates of one class from some other class, it's not obvious what is best for you. Probably you want some kind of "composition" relationship, where one of your classes has a reference to an instance of the other, but without understanding what the classes mean, it's not really obvious what would be best.